# ZKteco fingerprint scanner does not have a simulator, But I need any way to test my code for it for multiple devices

Tags: fingerprint, zkteco

I know that ZKteco fingerprint scanner does not have a simulator, But I need any way to test my code for it for multiple devices.
I have wrote a code and I need to test it while I don't have the device or able to buy one.

My code is in C# and using ZKTecho SDK

Any suggestions or work around please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate the DLL file. In SDK, at the end you will be calling connect, capture and compare functions of a DLL file. You can develop a simple DLL file and replace with actual one. Your DLL file should have the functions you used from the actual DLL, and the these should return the data of what the actual DLL returns while it captures the fingerprint and comparing the fingerprints.

This way, you can test your code without making a single line of code change from your software.